# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' using dojo toolkit 1.6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dojo, babeljs

I'm new to React and I'm in trouble in start React code into dojo 1.6 dojox.layout.ContentPane.

If i run it in some HTML online tester it works, inside a dojo `dojox/layout/ContentPane` it doesn't.

This code work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root">banana</div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root') );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This don't (only add a script tag on line 9):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root">banana</div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root') );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: post all the code not only react part

Comment: I posted an exemple.

Comment: by jsut adding dojo it wont work ? or what ? where is you r doojo code ?

Comment: The real code is a legacy dojo application, I cant post it here.
Anyway the exemple shows the error.

Comment: yes, could you please post it

Comment: Sorry i can't. Its my company legacy code.

Comment: any fix with below suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Seem problem with loader (require js) , try to import your dojo loader below all your react and babel script :

like :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<!-- dojo just below -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

See this working snippet :

```js
 
 ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world! Im created with react</h1>, document.getElementById('root') );
    
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"], function(BorderContainer,ContentPane) {
  var borderContainer = new BorderContainer({},"dojoContainer");
  
  var contentPanel = new ContentPane({
   region: "center",
    style: "min-height:125px; background-color:red;",
    content:"Hello I was created with dojo !"
  });

  
 borderContainer.addChild(contentPanel);
  contentPanel.startup();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body class="claro">

 
     
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
  <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  
  <div id="root">banana</div>
  <div id="dojoContainer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```